# Ignoring transparency for animated sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently using CGPath in order to ignore transparency for sprites so:

```
path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, endpoint-x, endpoint-y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 250);.....
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 50, 0);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

This works for 1 sprite per path. The problem is, my sprites are animated so it makes use of multiple sprites with different vertices (points). My question is, what is the best way to ignore transparency for animated(multiple) sprites? I was told that I can use this per frame but that would be way too tedious so there might be something easier than this.

Just additional info, I've already tried pixel perfect collision but it didn't work for me. Please help.